# Pick image from Gallery in android app : "Method called after release() "

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i tried to to pick image from Gallery in my android application but after that an error message appears :

Exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
```

Code :

```
public class ProductAfter extends Fragment{
......

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);

......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First Step :

You have to @Override this method to catch the call back from the Gallery to Fragment

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check with your Request code and do stuff with that 
}

Second Step:

 From the Gallery the call back will be directly to the Parent Activity, So you have to  @Override  the same method in the parent Activity 

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


   // here check for all the fragments where the method is overidden and callback reaches there 
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if (fragment != null)
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    }
```

Hope this will resolve you issues

in TabsPagerAdapter :

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {


        switch (index) {

        case 0:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new CategorieFragment();
        case 1:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new ProductBefore();         
        case 2:

            return new ProductAfter();

        case 3:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new CodeBarreAuto();



        }

        return null;
    }
```

when i change number cases --> case 2 by case 1 and case 1 by case 2  it's woks fine !!

Comment: but i don't know why !!